# disabling screensaver on Linux

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, gnome, kde

I all, i have need to disable screensaver for Gnome and KDE graphic environment on more server with RHEL4 and RHEL5.

Is there a way to do it at boot time or any other solution?

thank you very much.
Max

Comment: To be clear, screen saver or screen blanker, or both?

Comment: You could uninstall the screensavers - usually in a package with "screensaver" in the name

Comment: I have to say that the versions of Linux that were coming out back in 1995 had better configuration control for the screensaver than recent versions of linux.  Gnome and KDE have messed it all up IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gconftool-2 --set -t boolean /apps/gnome-screensaver/idle_activation_enabled false`

This is a per-user setting, so you could add this to the default settings like this:

`gconftool-2 --direct --config-source xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.defaults --set -t boolean /apps/gnome-screensaver/idle_activation_enabled false`

This seems to work for me.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to achieve the same only on my account on a CentOs system. Where should I put the above settings?